# How to retrieve json array from this simple json file?

Tags: android, jsonp

I am trying to retrieve "jsonarray Events" from the a json file below, first i get the whole response below in  "StringBuilder response". How to retrieve/parse Events jsonarray from StringBuilder response object?

```
{   
    Events:
    [
        { "event1": "recruitment", "location1":"lindholmen" },
        { "event1": "party",       "location1":"lisebrg" }
    ]    

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to parse the returned response to jsonArray then you iterate through the array and retrieve the information from each jsonObject using this code :

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.toString(); 
For(JSONObject jObject : jsonArray) {
String location = jObject.getString("location");
......
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: Well you parse the returned response to jsonArray then you iterate through the array and retrieve the information from each jsonObject

Comment: @Boukharist unless you edit that into the answer itself, your answer may be deleted.